# How to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, jlayer, musicg

I am creating a project in Android Studio using LibGDX, musicg and jlayer. The problem is when using any class from these libraries in the core project the error  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError appears. I have the libraries in jar on the folder libs of the core project.

It is not a multidex error since my project only has 18k methods.

Screenshots from the error and the gradle build:

> Log Error

```
W/dalvikvm: threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a2bc98)
W/dalvikvm: threadid=12: uncaught exception occurred
W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javazoom.jl.converter.Converter
W/System.err:     at com.beatshare.game.Utilities.Utils.sync(Utils.java:129)
W/System.err:     at Screens.ListMusicScreen.show(ListMusicScreen.java:44)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
W/System.err:     at Screens.MainMenuScreen$2.touchUp(MainMenuScreen.java:86)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:58)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchUp(Stage.java:353)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.processEvents(AndroidInput.java:379)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:457)
W/System.err:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1814)
W/System.err:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1517)
W/dalvikvm: threadid=12: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 794
                  Process: com.beatshare.game, PID: 29535
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javazoom.jl.converter.Converter
                      at com.beatshare.game.Utilities.Utils.sync(Utils.java:129)
                      at Screens.ListMusicScreen.show(ListMusicScreen.java:44)
                      at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
                      at Screens.MainMenuScreen$2.touchUp(MainMenuScreen.java:86)
                      at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:58)
                      at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchUp(Stage.java:353)
                      at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.processEvents(AndroidInput.java:379)
                      at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:457)
                      at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1814)
                      at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1517)
```

> Core build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/jl1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/musicg-1.4.2.0.jar')
}



eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}
```

> App build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "Beatshare"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.6'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }

}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"


    }

}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Comment: you can put your code and error log here instead of screenshot ?

Comment: Sorry, new to the site. But added the gradle code and error log.

Comment: Are you aware of what `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` does? You do not need the two lines after it

Comment: Yes, I know that will compile all jars on the libs folder but I wrote the other two just for paranoia. Tried everything with gradle to fix the error but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

`jlayer.jar` available in maven repo so compile in this way and remove `jlayer.jar` from libs folder:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile group: 'javazoom', name: 'jlayer', version: '1.0.1'
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')   
}
```

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**

This exception indicates that the JVM looked in its internal class definition data structure for the definition of a class and did not find it.

This is different than saying that it could not be loaded from the classpath. Usually this indicates that we previously attempted to load a class from the classpath, but it failed for some reason - now we're trying to use the class again (and thus need to load it, since it failed last time), but we're not even going to try to load it, because we failed loading it earlier (and reasonably suspect that we would fail again).

The earlier failure could be a `ClassNotFoundException` or an `ExceptionInInitializerError` (indicating a failure in the static initialization block) or any number of other problems. The point is, a `NoClassDefFoundError` is not necessarily a classpath problem.

Comment: That has solved the error with the jlayer but musicg still triggers the exactly same error.

Comment: I don't think so musicg in any repo so you need to compile through fileTree.